# Problem with oracle stored procedure - parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, ora-06502

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "LIQUIDACION_OBTENER" (
  p_Cuenta IN NUMBER, 
  p_Fecha IN DATE,
  p_Detalle OUT LIQUIDACION.FILADETALLE%TYPE
) IS

BEGIN 

  SELECT FILADETALLE
    INTO p_Detalle
    FROM Liquidacion
   WHERE (FILACUENTA = p_Cuenta)
     AND (FILAFECHA = p_Fecha);

END;
/
```

...and my c# code:

```
string liquidacion = string.Empty;

OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("Liquidacion_Obtener");            

command.BindByName = true;
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Cuenta", OracleDbType.Int64));
command.Parameters["p_Cuenta"].Value = cuenta;
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Fecha", OracleDbType.Date));
command.Parameters["p_Fecha"].Value = fecha;

command.Parameters.Add("p_Detalle", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);            

OracleConnectionHolder connection = null;

connection = this.GetConnection();
command.Connection = connection.Connection;
command.CommandTimeout = 30;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OracleDataReader lector = command.ExecuteReader();

while (lector.Read())
{
    liquidacion += ((OracleString)command.Parameters["p_Detalle"].Value).Value;
}
```

the thing is that when I try to put a value into the parameter "Fecha" (that is a date) the code gives me this error (when the line `command.ExecuteReader();` is executed)

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.LIQUIDACION_OBTENER", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I tried with the datetime and was not the problem, I eve tried with no input parameters and just the output and still got the same error. Aparently the problem is with the output parameter.
I already tried putting p_Detalle OUT VARCHAR2 instead of p_Detalle OUT LIQUIDACION.FILADETALLE%TYPE but it didn't work either

I hope my post is understandable..
thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Updated my answer - we need details to help you out further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably... this can be the problem. Try to use Oracle to_date function to match the date format.

If that doesn't work, as a last resort change the parameter to varchar and pass the date as a string to the stored procedure. Use to_date inside Oracle.

This way your stored procedure would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "LIQUIDACION_OBTENER" (
p_Cuenta IN NUMBER, 
p_Fecha IN VARCHAR,
p_Detalle OUT LIQUIDACION.FILADETALLE%TYPE
) IS

BEGIN 

    SELECT 
        FILADETALLE
    INTO
        p_Detalle
    FROM 
        Liquidacion
    WHERE 
        (FILACUENTA = p_Cuenta)
        AND (FILAFECHA = to_date(p_Fecha, 'yyyy-MON-dd'));

END;
```

[Oracle/PLSQL: To_Date Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: aparently the problem is the output parameter!! read again my post, I edited it (sorry I'm new, don't know how to do this very well)

Answer (score 2):

What is the output from:

```
DESC LIQUIDACION
```

The out parameter notation you have is correct:

```
p_Detalle OUT LIQUIDACION.FILADETALLE%TYPE
```

...so that leaves the issue to be in the C# code, when converting the Oracle data type to its .NET sibling.  I've seen it before, when using Java...

### Previously

---

If the data type of `LIQUIDACION.filafecha` is VARCHAR2/etc (not DATE), use:

```
SELECT la.filadeetaile
  INTO p_Detalle
  FROM LIQUIDACION la
 WHERE la.filacuenta = p_Cuenta
   AND la.filafecha = TO_CHAR(p_Fecha, 'YYYY-MON-DD');
```

...or you could change the parameter to match the data type:

```
p_Fecha IN LIQUIDACION.filafecha%TYPE
```

...and correct the C# code to pass the proper information.

Ideally, a date column should be a DATE data type...

Comment: aparently the problem is the output parameter!!
read again my post, I edited it (sorry I'm new, don't know how to do this very well)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use to_date(p_fecha, 'yyyy-mmm-dd') when setting the parameter:

```
  command.Parameters["p_Fecha"].Value = to_date(fecha, 'yyyy-MON-dd');
```

Comment: I saw that the format mask for month is MON instead of MMM, then you must use yyyy-mon-dd

Comment: aparently the problem is the output parameter!! read again my post, I edited it (sorry I'm new, don't know how to do this very well)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are not defining the size of the output parameter:

```
command.Parameters.Add("p_Detalle", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

I don't know what ADO defaults to, but it is obviously smaller the length of `LIQUIDACION.FILADETALLE%TYPE`.  Oracle hurls ORA-06502 when the receiving variable is too small or of the wrong datatype.  Try something like (adjusting the size to match the database column definition):

```
command.Parameters["p_Detalle"].Size = 20;
```